# Visualization of risk table with 4 dimensions

Tags: r, visualization, data-visualization

I have a data set consisting of customers, distributed to distinct and complete countries and customer levels. Each country/level combination has a size and a risk attribute. The risk attribute indicates how big the problem is, the size attribute how large the associated population is.

Example data (R): http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=KVMCtmz8&version=12

How would you visualize this data in order to show all 4 dimensions (conceptually, not necessarily coding-wise)?

My initial idea was to create a 2-dimensional table/lattice (country x level), with the size as bubbles and the risk as color scale, but I'm worried about the effectiveness of bubble plots.

EDIT: code link correction

Comment: Scatter plot/ bubble plot is fine, but I would use size as x, risk as y, color for the country and size for the level.

Comment: Really depends on what relationship you are trying to show. If it is differences in risk vs size across countries, then `ggplot(df, aes(x = size, y = risk)) + geom_point(aes(color = country)) + facet_wrap(~custlevel)` might work. I would plot on a google bubble chart where you can quickly change axis and labels, and then decide what you want to show

Comment: I am trying to give decision support in which areas (country/level combination) to address risks. I.e. risk is the most important factor, relativized by size. County and level are used to either focus attention ("German gold customer market is my responsibility") or to compare.

Answer (score 0):

I will keep the answer separate from what you *should* do for your data - this completely depends on the trends within your data and the message you are trying to convey.

Using `ggplot2`, the ways which you can summarize your data with a `geom_point` object are captured by the `aes()` argument. These are:

- x
- y
- alpha
- colour
- fill
- shape
- size
- stroke

This gives a potential **8** dimensions you can graph your data on. A few of these, specifically color and fill, you can only use in combination with the right shape (pch = 21 - 25, see [*here*](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape)). As well, `shape` cannot be mapped to a continuous variable, so you are limited there as well.

That said, I would never suggest using all of them at once, as your graph would become very hard to interpret, but theoretically you could.

Sample Code

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = size, y = risk)) + geom_point(aes(color = country, size = custlevel))
```

[image]

For discrete variables, a second lever you could pull is with facets. This can add (theoretically, not recommended) infinite dimensions to your data, depending on how many subsections you need. For example:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = size, y = risk)) + geom_point(aes(color = country)) + 
facet_wrap(~custlevel)
```

[image]

You can use `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`, adding additional dimensions within the argument (i.e. `facet_wrap(~custlevel + country)` or `facet_wrap(~custlevel + country + size)`

Again, this would not be recommended as you decrease readability. However, these are all the tools at your disposal.